# Can i get alpha and boolean type from a match in ocaml?

Tags: types, match, ocaml

I'm doing a recursive propositional calculator but I have a problem using a dictionary, I'm using pair list like a dictionary and my own function lookup to search for a value in the dictionary.

Now lookup returns an alpha type, but in my main function (calcPrep) the match must return a bool, I don't see a problem whit the syntaxis, at the end that alpha type can be a bool...

If I change

```
| '('::variable::')'::_ -> lookup (variable, dictionary)
```

to

```
| '('::variable::')'::_ -> true
```

the match works, but obviously, I didn't get the value of the variable.

I'm thinking of use maps as a dictionary instead pair list, but it's more complex to me...

Here is my code until now

```
let rec lookup x l = 
    match l with
    | [] -> raise Not_found
    | (key, value)::rest -> 
        if key = x then 
            value
        else 
            lookup x rest
```

```
let rec calcPrep charList dictionary=
    let n = List.length charList in
    match charList with
    | '('::variable::')'::_ -> lookup (variable, dictionary)
    | '('::'!'::_ -> not (calcPrep (sublist 2 (n-1) charList) dictionary)
    | _ ->
        let pos = getPositionOperator charList 0 0 in
        let operator = List.nth charList pos in 
        match operator with
        | '&' -> calcPrep (sublist 1 (pos - 1) charList) dictionary && calcPrep (sublist (pos + 1) (n - 2) charList) dictionary
        | '|' -> calcPrep (sublist 1 (pos - 1) charList) dictionary && calcPrep (sublist (pos + 1) (n - 2) charList) dictionary
        | _ -> failwith ("Incorrect operator: " ^ String.make 1 (List.nth charList (pos - 1)))
```

Comment: The error at the console is: This expression has type ((char * 'a) * 'b) list -> 'b
 but an expression was expected of type bool

Comment: I see at least one obvious problem with the syntax: you apply lookup to a tuple as `lookup (variable, dictionary)` but according to its definition it expects 2 params (value and a list), so it should be applied as `lookup variable dictionary`. Next thing is that `not x` expects `x` to be `bool`. Is your calcPrep intended to return bool always? If so, did you try to specify its type explicitly to help the typechecker? (P.S. I can't check your code in toplevel because it lacks the definitions of `sublist` and `getPositionOperator`; `sublist` is more or less obvious, the second one is not...)

Comment: lol, I'm so sleepy :c yep it was the problem thanks <3

Comment: Style suggestion: Note that both cases: `'&'` and `'|'` have the same result. Rather: `'&' | '|' -> calcPrep (sublist 1 (pos - 1) charList) dictionary && calcPrep (sublist (pos + 1) (n - 2) charList) dictionary`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, alpha, aka `'a`, doesn't mean "anything", it is a type variable that should be considered in a context. For example, in the type of a function,

```
val find: ('k,'a) list -> 'k -> 'a
```

we have two type variables `'k` and `'a`, with the `'k` denoting the type of keys, and `'a` denoting the type of values. Therefore, when you apply this function to some list, e.g., `find [1, "one"; 2, "two"]` the `'k` variable will be instantiated to `int` and `'a` to `string`, and the type of this expression will be `int -> string`.

Second, a function that checks whether a particular key or element is present in a container is usually called `mem`. It could be easily implemented via the `find` function, that search for the element, e.g.,

```
let mem ls k = try ignore (find ls k); false with Not_found -> true
```

This function will have type `('k,'a) list -> 'k -> bool`.

In the modern OCaml, it is prefered to use a more explicit `'a option` type as the return type of the find function, instead of throwing an exception, since the former appears in the type of the function and is harder to miss. So if you have a `find` function returning `'a option`, then the implementation will look like this

```
let mem ls ks = match find ls k with None -> false | Some _ -> true
```

Comment: The `lookup` function the OP has written appears to replicate [`List.assoc`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/List.html#VALassoc) from the standard library.